# frida：java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.content.Intent[]

Tags: android, frida

problem
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.content.Intent[]

code show as below：
frida-js:

```js
var ProcessManagerG = Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g')
var doInBackground = ProcessManagerG.doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')
doInBackground.implementation = function (intentArr) {

    doInBackground.call(this, intentArr)

}
```

Not a few other ways.Here is all the code.Other code has been removed.

1. Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.content.Intent[]

```js
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g').doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;').implementation = function (intentArr) {
        try {
            return this.doInBackground.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})
```

2. Error: doInBackground(): argument types do not match any of: .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')

```js
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g').doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;').implementation = function (intentArr) {
        try {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = intentArr.length; i < len; i++) {
                // console.log(arguments[i], Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[i]))
                send(intentArr[i]) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: android.content.Intent>']}
                arr.push(Java.cast(intentArr[i], Java.use('android.content.Intent')))
                send(arr) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: android.content.Intent>']}
            }
            return this.doInBackground.apply(this, arr); // Error: doInBackground(): argument types do not match any of: .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})
```

3. Error: doInBackground(): argument types do not match any of: .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')

```
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g').doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;').implementation = function (intentArr) {
        try {
            send(intentArr) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: android.content.Intent>']}
            var arr = Java.array('Landroid.content.Intent;', intentArr);
            send(arr) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: android.content.Intent>']}
            return this.doInBackground.apply(this, arr); // Error: doInBackground(): argument types do not match any of: .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})
```

4. Error: doInBackground(): argument types do not match any of: .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')

```js
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g').doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;').implementation = function (intentArr) {
        try {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = intentArr.length; i < len; i++) {
                send(intentArr[i]) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: android.content.Intent>']}
                arr.push(Java.cast(intentArr[i], Java.use('android.content.Intent')))
                send(arr) // {'type': 'send', 'payload': ['<instance: android.content.Intent>']}
            }
            return this.doInBackground(Java.array('java.lang.Object', arr));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})
```

java:

```java
public Intent doInBackground(Intent... intentArr) {}
```

smali:

```
.method protected synthetic doInBackground([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    .registers 2

    .line 61
    check-cast p1, [Landroid/content/Intent;

    invoke-virtual {p0, p1}, Lcom/xxx/xxx/processManager/g;->a([Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/Intent;

    move-result-object p1

    return-object p1
.end method
```

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is the posted `doInBackground([Ljava/lang/Object;)` method the only one in this class (and super classes)?

Comment: yes, only one ...

Comment: Looks like the error here：check-cast p1, [Landroid/content/Intent; @Robert

Comment: This means that the error is independent of Frida. It is just a problem of the app you try to hook.

Comment: Not an app problem!I remove the hook code, app is ok.

Comment: Is a problem with my hook code

Comment: If there is a problem in your code then the code is not present in the question.

Comment: First paragraph "code show as below： frida-js:"

Comment: As you are just forwarding an existing call this can't be problem source. May be the app detects frida and intentionally crashes? Try to attach frida without any script.

Comment: Other hooks can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From smali output, it seems the compiler has rewritten the `doInBackground` method to take an Object array, cast it to an Intent array, and pass it to an internal method called `a` (Lcom/xxx/xxx/processManager/g;->a). You must use this `a` method.

You should try something like:

```js
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('com.xxx.xxx.processManager.g').doInBackground.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;').implementation = function (objectArray) {
        return this.a.overload('[Landroid.content.Intent;').call(this, intentArray); 
    }
})
```

Comment: var intentArray = Java.cast(objectArray, '[Landroid/content/Intent;') => TypeError: undefined not callable (property '$borrowClassHandle' of '[Landroid/content/Intent;')

Comment: Can Java.cast cast arrays directly?

Comment: I've edited my response, try again please. The casting part is not so important I'm sure you can solve it, but the solution to your issue is definitely related to the a method.

Comment: Succeeded: this.a.overload('[Landroid.content.Intent;').call(this, intentArray)

Comment: But why can't I call doInBackground directly?

Comment: This will do: implementation = function (objectArray) {return this.a.overload('[Landroid.content.Intent;').call(this, objectArray); }

Comment: Not necessary: var intentArray = Java.array('android.content.Intent', objectArray);

Comment: Great! I think the compiler uses an Object array for doInBackground because of param destructuring (``Intent... intentArr``) or some optimization